# Redirecting from http to https in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

> This is a [canonical question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986) about redirecting from http to https in Apache
>
> Related:
>
> - [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512)

I have an Appache web server which serves both `http://example.com/` and `https://example.com/`. I want to redirect all http requests to https. Currently I'm using this `.htaccess` rule to redirect http requests to https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It's working as expected for `example.com` but the same rule is not working for sub links, when I access existing links, like `example.com/about` it will still load in http, no redirection happens for existing links.

How can I make Apache redirect all http requests to https?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should configure Apache Virtualhosts to do the job. RewriteMod isn't the appropriate solution for this case and `.htaccess` isn't either.

In your httpd.conf or equivalent use the following lines accordingly your needs. Edit it to your domain and site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On

   ** Additional configurations here **

</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this clarifies the procedure.

Comment: This is working perfectly on my server, but the issue I'm facing in a shared account, where I don't have access to httpd conf, how can I implement the same in .htaccess

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, this site probably isn't for you.

Comment: The `NameVirtualHost` line is no longer needed in current Apache versions. See https://serverfault.com/q/735233/214507

Comment: @Augustin If you are on a shared server then the Pro Webmasters stack is really the place to ask: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "`ServerName www.example.com example.com`" - It's not valid to have mutliple server names / arguments with the `ServerName` directive. Maybe you're thinking of the `ServerAlias` directive?

Answer (score 1):

On shared hosting, when you don't have better options, you could modify your rewrite rule in the .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

First, the RegEx at the beginning matches to all requests, including everything behind the domain.

Then, a HTTP Result code of 301 (moved permanently) is thrown back to the client together with the new URL. Most of the modern browsers remember the new URL, in this case the httpS, and redirect to the new url automatically the next time the user calls up the website.

I hope this helps, kind regards

Comment: If http and https share the same directory, probably he will also need the mentioned `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`, otherwise it will loop forever :)

Comment: I tried above step, but it still not working for existing links like domain.com/about etc, but adding Redirect permanent / https://example.com/ in http.conf working in another server.

Comment: Using Easy HTTPS Redirection plugin with wordpress solved my problem

Comment: @Augustin "...with wordpress" - If you are using WordPress then the HTTP to HTTPS redirect would need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, _before_ the existing WordPress directives. The behaviour you have described in the question is consistent with having put the directives in the wrong place (ie. _after_ the WordPress front-controller).

Comment: "you could modify your rewrite rule in the .`htaccess`" - In terms of actually getting the redirect to function, the only significant take-away from this (over the directive in the question) is the `L` flag (which is not specifically addressed). The `L` flag is _required_ in order to prevent the request being further rewritten (by the WP front-controller that presumably _follows_) which would otherwise mangle the redirect.