# Automatically redirecting http to https with multiple domains - files referenced from within code

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I know there are duplicate questions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/683383/apache-http-to-https-redirection) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever) but these haven't solved my issues.

When localhost is typed in the browser's url bar, it is correctly redirected to `https://localhost`, but all calls within my code to load files with `http` are not being redirected or rewritten to `https`. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static/css/colwidth.min.css">
```

I have tried `Redirect permanent / https://localhost/` in the Apache configuration files in the `VirtualHost` sections and I have also tried `RewriteRule` with `.htaccess`

The `Firefox` error I am getting is:

> Blocked loading mixed active content “`http://static/css/colwidth.min.css`”

I would appreciate help understanding how to do this with **both** Apache config and `.htaccess` (I know `.htaccess` is not the preferred method - but I still would like to understand why it isn't working)

http:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/path/to/root"
    ServerName localhost
    Redirect permanent / https://localhost/

    <Directory "D:/Website/path/to/root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/path/to/root"
    ServerName static
    Redirect permanent / https://static/

    <Directory "D:/Website/path/to/root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/path/to/root"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
    <Directory "D:/Website/path/to/root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "c:/xampp/apache/bin/wtr.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/xampp/apache/bin/wtr.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "c:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    CustomLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

https:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/path/to/root"
    ServerName static:443
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

    <Directory "D:/Website/path/to/root">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "c:/xampp/apache/bin/static.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/xampp/apache/bin/static.key"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "c:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    CustomLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
    # For SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
    # I also tried:
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R=301]

    #Rules for Versioned Static Files
    RewriteRule ^(js|js-common|css|css-common|img|img-common)/(.+)\.([0-9])+\.(js|css|php|jpg|gif|png)(.*)$ $1/$2.$4$5 [L]

    #rename invalid file and directory requests
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?redirectroot=true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The **Firefox error** I am getting is:

That's the problem... the *browser* is triggering this error *before* the request even reaches your server, so any attempt to redirect on the server is too late.

If the page itself is redirected to `https://...` then all referenced resources within that page must also use `https://...` as well, otherwise you get the "mixed content" warning as above. This is basic browser security in order to prevent any *secure* content being leaked over an *insecure* (HTTP) connection.

Instead of using absolute URLs (that include the *scheme*) in the HTML you can use protocol relative URLs instead, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//static/css/colwidth.min.css">
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Hopefully having relative URL will work everywhere - I will give it a try. I know there was a reason I added `http` to my addresses at some point. Thanks.

Comment: However, you would have a problem if this external(?) resource is not available on HTTPS.

Comment: The example has an error. You either use `//example.com/static/css/colwidth.min.css` or `/static/css/colwidth.min.css`. The first one is protocol relative, the latter is domain and protocol relative.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes - sort of. Although it would seem that in this instance `static` is actually the (cookieless) _domain_ from which the static resources are being served, not a subdirectory. This would seem to be consistent with the code, where `static` is used in place of the domain/host. (However, the use of the word "static" is indeed misleading.)

Comment: Ah yes, it was sloppy reading from my part :) Although it is odd to use a top-level-domain in this case. Maybe it was just an example to protect the main domain.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - I created the domain `static` to serve files without cookies. It points to the same directory as localhost - the only difference being no cookies. The reason for not having it as a subdirectory is that I can serve any file from any directory on the server this way (e.g. /css or /js or /img). I do this on my live server as well as I am not big enough to justify the cost of a cdn.

Comment: But the domain cannot be simply `static`, unless you own the top-level domain `static`. It needs to be `static.example.com` or so.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - Yes I do "own" the top level domain `static`. This setup is on a development machine and so I have complete ownership of all domains - `localhost` and `static`. I could have set it up as you say.