# How can I point my custom domain to a google cloud instance

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, ip, google-compute-engine

So, I got a domain, suputamadre.es

I launched a google cloud instance and assigned an IP to it, say 1.2.3.4

I launched my django server to listen on 0.0.0.0:80

I try to connect by going on chrome to http://1.2.3.4 or http://1.2.3.4:80 and it works. Great.

Set up my domain on Google Cloud DNS (domain bought from GoDaddy, so pointed the nameservers to Google Cloud)

Set up an A record suputamadre.es pointing to 1.2.3.4

Going to cmd and doing a ping suputamadre.es returns 1.2.3.4

Going in a browser and writing suputamadre.es returns a Connection refused error, however suputamadre.es:80 works. Why is that? How can I just point this domain to my server? Tried doing a CNAME, didn't work either...

While on topic, is there any way of pointing it to both :80 and :443 to support SSL without running two concurrent servers? Or even point the domain to 1.2.3.4:8000 without having to use a redirect given that SRV don't work in browsers?

Thanks a bunch. I've been stuck on this for two days now, and whatever I try to google doesn't seem to work for me. Not to mention that if I google something about "DNS A register" google thinks I'm talking about *a* register...

Comment: You don't have a server listening on port 443 (i.e. `https`), while there is one running on port 80 (i.e. `http`). `A` records point just to an IP address, no port. `SRV` records contain a port, but they are not used with `HTTP/HTTPS`, that by default use port `80` and `443`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your problem is partially solved. If I put http://suputamadre.es into my browser I can see your "Django setup complete" page, so that seems to be working.

With regards to the :80 vs :443 SSL question, this is typically done with a redirect on the port 80. IE: A user types in http://suputamadre.es which is received by your webserver on port 80 and then the web server sends back a redirect to http**s**://suputamadre.es (which is served on port 443 by default which the browser will use without having to specify it). This way all traffic is served via http**s** on port 443. Anything to port 80 is redirected to port 443.

- To setup redirects in Nginx, see here: [In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom)
- To setup redirects in Apache, see here: [Redirecting from http to https in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/683383/redirecting-from-http-to-https-in-apache)

Answer (score 0):

As DrewZa indicated, you can use nginx for these purposes. It's a nice lightweight webserver. Look here:

[Installing NGINX Plus on the Google Cloud Platform](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus-google-cloud-platform/#)

As for port forwarding from 80 to 443:

create a server entry in your nginx.conf file and you can do the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  suputamadre.es;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
    }
 }
```

This will redirect all requests from 80 to 443